# jQuery Sort nested JSON objects by date?

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, date, object

I've searched `StackOverflow` before I made this question but I can't find the solutions to my case. 
I'm receiving objects from multiple `Facebook Graph API` calls (see first image).
What I would like to do is to sort my objects by a date (`event.start_time`).
**Is this possible with or without creating an extra array?**

The structure of the objects is visible in the second picture.

the variable "`event`" holds all the objects.

**UPDATE**
I made a global array and pushed all the event objects to it, it's now an array so it should be sortable. I just don't know how to, please help.

```
        var arr = []; //global array to sort event objects
    //function is called somewhere
    function makeEvents(ids, infowindow, map, accessToken) {
            var currentTime = dateFormat("date", new Date(), true);
            //console.log(currentTime);
            var display = document.getElementById("all");
            var carousel = document.getElementById("carousel-inner");
             // console.log(ids);

            FB.api('/',
            {ids : ids}, 
            function (pages) {
              if(pages) {
                $.each(pages, function(page_key, page_value) {
                    var id = page_value.id;
                    //display.innerHTML += '<tr>';
                    //console.log(id);
                     //if date search changed, since date search input
                    FB.api('/'+ id +'/events?access_token='+ accessToken +'&since='+ currentTime, function (events) { //&offset=0   &until=2016-02-31
                        //console.log(events.data);

                      if(events) {
                        //console.log(events.data)
                        $.each(events.data, function(events_key, events_value) {
                          FB.api('/'+ events_value.id + '?fields=id,name,cover,description,start_time,place,ticket_uri,picture', function (event) {
                            if(event) {                                 
                             //console.log(event);
                             arr.push(event);//fill array
                              }
                          });
                        });
                      }
                    });
                   // display.innerHTML += '</tr>';
                });
              }
            });  
    }
    console.log(arr);
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
     if(a.start_time < b.start_time)
       return -1;
     if(a.start_time > b.start_time)
       return 1;
     return 0;
    });
```

This shouldn't work since I'm not deep enough in the array.

[image]

**SOLVED** Had to use a timeout function because the array sorted before it was completely filled which made me think it didn't sort at all. If there's a better way to check if the array is done filling, please let me know :)

```
   setTimeout(function(){
      arr = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.name.localeCompare( b.name );
      });
      console.log(arr);
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: You don't already have an Array? If you do then this should be trivial with the built in sort and a comparator function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use the JavaScript sort function like this ? -

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.start_time < b.start_time)
        return -1;
    if(a.start_time > b.start_time)
        return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mhccnpkp/

**UPDATE:** At first I thought this was just a simple sorting problem you are having, but now I see that you are trying to sort the result from a list of `ajax` calls. In this case you have to wait for all the calls to finish loading and the main fact is, it is not guaranteed that each call will end sequentially. So I would suggest you use a semaphore to make sure all calls are ended and then call sort to sort your array. Something like this -

```
var arr = []; //global array to sort event objects
//function is called somewhere
var semaphore = 0; //the semaphore
function makeEvents(ids, infowindow, map, accessToken) {
    ....

    FB.api('/',
    {ids : ids}, 
    function (pages) {
      if(pages) {
        $.each(pages, function(page_key, page_value) {

            semaphore += 1; // increase the semaphore for each call
            ....
            FB.api('/'+ id +'/events?access_token='+ accessToken +'&since='+ currentTime, function (events) { //&offset=0   &until=2016-02-31
                //console.log(events.data);

              semaphore -= 1; //reduce semaphore count, sicne this call is completed 
              .....

                  semaphore += 1; // increase the semaphore for next call

                  FB.api('/'+ events_value.id + '?fields=id,name,cover,description,start_time,place,ticket_uri,picture', function (event) {

                    ....

                    semaphore -= 1; //reduce semaphore count, sicne this call is completed 

                    //check if all calls completed
                    if(semaphore == 0){
                        arr.sort(function(a, b){
                            if(a.start_time < b.start_time)
                                return -1;
                            if(a.start_time > b.start_time)
                                return 1;
                            return 0;
                        });
                    }                   
                  });

                });
              }

            });
           ...
        });
      }
    });  
}
console.log(arr);
```

**BTW**, this is very basic checking. This will only work if all calls succeeds. So you might also wanna add some check and an error handlers and decrease the semaphore in the error handlers also. Other wise one unsuccessful call will make the system wait indefinitely.

Comment: returns an error: event.sort is not a function, .sort only applies to arrays I think?

Comment: make sure `events` is an array. I have added a jsfiddle

Comment: events or event? these are 2 different objects.

Comment: The code is to sort any array. Just use the appropriate variable there. Wasn't it obvious?

Comment: I have an array now to sort but it's an array filled with objects, that would make something like arr.object.sort(function(a,b){ ... }); ?? Or should I loop it first ?

Comment: That's what I exactly did in the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/mhccnpkp/. x is an array of 2 objects.

Comment: I had to use a timeout function since the array wasn't done filling even after I sorted it, it made me think it didn't work but now it does, thanks a lot   
    setTimeout(function(){
          arr = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.name.localeCompare( b.name );
          });
          console.log(arr);
        }, 5000);

Comment: Yup, I added an edit to the answer, you can also use that instead of timeout.

Comment: Oh great, thanks. But I probs shouldn't do that within the each loops?

Comment: May be, I currently don't have a test environment here, so cannot test, but you get the basic idea. Just make sure you track all the ajax calls.

Comment: The semaphore solution totally rocks! :D Thanks a lot, this will help me a lot in my first API mashup assignment.

Comment: have you got any idea why I only get 1 result when I fill the array after `if(semaphore == 0) {` while I get all results when I fill it before checking the semaphore? this `arr.push(event); if(semaphore == 0){` 
gives all results but this just one: `if(semaphore == 0){ arr.push(event);`

Comment: Because the code inside `if(semaphore == 0)` only runs when all others are executed and this is the last request. So if you push inside that, you are only pushing the last item and ignoring all others, because for others that condition is false.

Comment: Oh nice to know, one last thing :p would it be possible to apply `JQuery.unique(arr);` somehow? I already tried it but gives doubles

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = []; //global array to sort event objects
function makeEvents(ids, infowindow, map, accessToken) {
        var currentTime = dateFormat("date", new Date(), true);
        //console.log(currentTime);
        var display = document.getElementById("all");
        var carousel = document.getElementById("carousel-inner");
        // console.log(ids);

        FB.api('/',
        {ids : ids}, 
        function (pages) {
            if(pages) {
                $.each(pages, function(page_key, page_value) {
                    var id = page_value.id;
                    //display.innerHTML += '<tr>';
                    //console.log(id);
                    //if date search changed, since date search input
                    FB.api('/'+ id +'/events?access_token='+ accessToken +'&since='+ currentTime, function (events) { //&offset=0   &until=2016-02-31
                        //console.log(events.data);

                        if(events) {
                            //console.log(events.data)
                            $.each(events.data, function(events_key, events_value) {
                                FB.api('/'+ events_value.id + '?fields=id,name,cover,description,start_time,place,ticket_uri,picture', function (event) {
                                    if(event) {                                 
                                        arr.push(event);
                                        shortArray();
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    // display.innerHTML += '</tr>';
                });
            }
        });  
    }


    function shortArray(){
        arr.sort(function(a, b){
            if(a.start_time < b.start_time)
                return -1;
            if(a.start_time > b.start_time)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }
```